# Javascript flattening an array of arrays but I'm getting error in my for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

I have an array of arrays.  Some of the arrays have multiple arrays within them that I'd like to flatten.  Here is what I cam up with:

```
_(o).forEach(function(array) {
    for (var i=0; i<= array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].length > 1) {
            _.flatten(array)
        }
    }
});
```

This is the array of arrays in my JS console.

```
[Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]
```

Here's another look at them, where you can see that some arrays have more than one array within them.

```
    0: Array[1]0: Array[1]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
    1: Array[1]0: Array[1]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
    2: Array[1]0: Array[1]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
    3: Array[1]0: Array[1]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
    4: Array[1]0: Array[2]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
    5: Array[1]0: Array[2]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
    6: Array[1]0: Array[1]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
    length: 7 __proto__: Array[0]
```

I get the following error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

I'm starting with the following object:

```
Object {OPxE8PPWuC: Array[1], Pxfus72LQL: Array[1], YUiapfcXac: Array[1], fTfCZU1zFs: Array[1], kTC0RwDalJ: Array[2]…}
OPxE8PPWuC: Array[1]
Pxfus72LQL: Array[1]
YUiapfcXac: Array[1]
fTfCZU1zFs: Array[1]
kTC0RwDalJ: Array[2]
yCDDEWoiwM: Array[2]
zP8ZcapePl: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
```

There are 8 arrays in that object but two of the arrays have two arrays within them.  I'd like to have 8 arrays but each of the arrays would be one level deep.  The two arrays that have two arrays, I'd merge them into one bigger array.

Comment: It's `i  < array.length` (not `<=`). Regardless, are you horribly mixing underscore with native loops?

Comment: Thanks but why isn't it <=? What's wrong with mixing btw. Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: So, do you just want one very long array, no nesting at all, or just flatten the arrays in the main array that have arrays? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @rashadb if `i==array.length` then `array[i] === undefined` so you get exception when try `array[i].length` all it because start index in js array is 0.

Comment: I want to flatten the array in the main array that have arrays. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: I've also tried: 

_.map(o, function(n){return _.flatten(n);})

but that doesn't seem to work either

that way I remove the for loop and there's no weird mixing

Comment: can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... but are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/n63bvbjL/

Comment: @ Mac.
I tried to run it but nothing happened. I tried the code on my machine and it doesn't provide the right result. I hope the edit I made above helps. Simply put I have 7 arrays.  I want to keep 7 arrays.  I just want each array to be as shallow as possible so any array that has more than one array in I want to flatten so that no array has multiple arrays in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the cut down version of the below code. This uses `_.flatten` from `underscore` which basically replaces the `recurse` function in my longer code.

```
function toType(x) {
  return ({}).toString.call(x).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
};

function flatten(arr) {
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (toType(arr[i]) === 'array') {
            out.push(_.flatten(arr[i]));
        } else {
            out.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ddkLwa6/5/)

This is the rather long-winded version from which it was taken. No libraries used, just completely vanilla JS.

```
// toType is used to get an accurate name for the JS
// data structures
function toType(x) {
  return ({}).toString.call(x).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
};

// the flatten function
function flatten(arr) {
  var out = [];

  // loop over each element in the array
  // if it's an array, call recurse with the element and
  // and an empty array as arguments
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (toType(arr[i]) === 'array') {
      out.push(recurse(arr[i], []));

    // otherwise add it to the output array
    } else {
      out.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

// this function keeps looping over arrays until they are
// flattened
function recurse(arr, out) {
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (toType(arr[i]) === 'array') {
        recurse(arr[i], out);
      } else {
        out.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

var arr = [[1], [[2, 3, [3, 4, 1]], 4], 78];
var result = flatten(arr); // [[1], [2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4], 78]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ddkLwa6/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following. Loop through the object, and run the [underscore.js flatten method](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) on it's value.

```js
var obj = {
  one: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  two: [6, 7, [8, 9], 10]
}

for (var prop in obj) {
  obj[prop] = _.flatten(obj[prop])
}

alert(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

The objects properties will then only contain a single array.

Comment: That won't work. I still need 7 arrays. I only want removed the arrays within the arrays.

Comment: So you want the nested arrays to be removed, as in deleted? The above code will 'flatten' the arrays.

Comment: I have lodash installed, so that is not the limiting factor. Your answer does what i'd like it to do but the console.log and alert only bring me back one of the 7 arrays.

Comment: I don't want the information in the nested arrays to be deleted I just want the information from both arrays inside of one array.

Comment: So instead of `[1, [2, 3, [4, 5]], [6]]` you want `[1, [2, 3, 4, 5], [6]]`.

Comment: Nope. I like what his code does in this answer as demonstrated. I just want it to work that way in my case. Instead of getting back 7 flat arrays, when I run his code on my my JS console I get one array of the seven [child]. 

I run: 


for (var prop in p){
                                p[prop] = _.flatten(p[prop])
                            }

                            console.log(p[prop]);

Comment: You need to do console.log(p) to get the entire object. Your only outputting the last item that has been through the loop with console.log(p[prop])

Comment: So when you answered "I want to flatten the array in the main array that have arrays" that wasn't what you wanted, and what I wrote above, while what you wanted, is incorrect?

Comment: This is tough to describe over words. Here is the situation:
{[array], [array], [array], [arra], [array], [[array],[array]], [[array],[array]]}.

The two arrays that have two arrays, I'd like to flatten/merge those two arrays so that all of the values of the two arrays are still there but are all together in one array so that the situation looks like:

{[array], [array], [array], [arra], [array], [array], [array]}

I have created both an object of 7 arrays and an array of 7 arrays so I could easily work with either to get the solution described above. I've not gotten Mac's code to work for me.

Comment: To be clear, I want to keep 7 arrays in total with no array having arrays in them.

Comment: From what I understand, the JS fiddle I posted about 58 mins ago does this for arrays, and the code above in my answer does this for an object... and the vanilla JS Andy wrote in his answer also does this for arrays!

Comment: Look, I'm just trying to get it to work on my machine. I'm a total beginner and I've been coding for 20 hours. I"m not trying to be confusing or an asshole . . . I'm just a guy trying to build something and I'm confused right now.  I don't know why the code above doesn't work other than to say that it very clearly returns a single object with a single array in it.

Comment: I keep getting a solution with an array that has an array in it with two children. Do you know what this is about?

Comment: Hey rashadb, no worries. I think you should create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code in. Then things should become a lot clearer.

Comment: @rashadb, I've just posted a cut-down version of my working code which uses underscore.

Comment: Thanks Andy and no worries Mac. I think I understand.  I'm passing out - I just finished an all nighter . . .